# How to get quickcheck failure details from hspec being run with cabal test

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck, hspec

I am using hspec with quickcheck, as per http://hspec.github.io/quickcheck.html

however, on failures, I simply get that a failure happened in a spec, no details about the data used by quickcheck so I can start diagnosing the failure. How do I get this detail out when running tests via cabal?

Comment: Could you post an example? So far I didn't have any problems with hspec+QuickCheck.

Comment: Turned out it was my implications being too specific - quickcheck actually gave up before it found anything that met my criteria - but I was confused by the message.